# How to Remove special Characters from Java String at the end and at the beginning

Tags: java, android, android-appcompat

lets say i have a string like

`String examplestring = "%,.&/)"hello, mynameis, Fatih-Mehmet!And yours?insidedot.2874d3"(.)§("`

And i would want to extract the core part of

`String goalstring = "hello, mynameis, Fatih-Mehmet!And yours?insidedot.2874d3"`

So keeping all special characters within the core but removing all special characters from the end and from the beginning of the string, how could I achieve that?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to extract a single double quoted term from inside the string, surrounded by other possible content at the start or end, we could phrase your requirement as:

```java
String examplestring = "%,.&/)\"hello, mynameis, Fatih-Mehmet!And yours?insidedot.2874d3\"(.)§(";
examplestring = examplestring.replaceAll("^[^\"]*\"|\"[^\"]*$", "");
System.out.println(examplestring);

// hello, mynameis, Fatih-Mehmet!And yours?insidedot.2874d3
```